# Editing photographs in paper

Tags: publications, writing

When using photographs for papers (assuming they've been taking by the author), to what extent can they be retouched and (a) be used without mention of retouching or (b) used but require mention of retouching?

I imagine that levels adjustment and cropping would generally fall under (a), but other types of processing give me more pause.  For instance, while stitching photographs together seems innocuous enough, it often necessarily involves interpolation.  And if some interpolation is acceptable, where would the line be drawn?  Power lines in front of a building or dust/scratches on older photographers seem like they'd be okay, but restoring a larger block area seems more dubious.

To what extent might these practices vary by field?  (I imagine astronomy and architecture probably have quite different standard practices)

Comment: This seems very context-dependent. What's your field? What role do the photographs have in your argument? What are the photographs showing - distant galaxies that are invisible anyway to the eye, evidence of a historical event, the magnified rhizomes of some plant? In many or most contexts, there is no such thing as an unedited photograph.

Comment: https://scholarlykitchen.sspnet.org/2016/05/02/image-manipulation-cleaning-up-the-scholarly-record/

Comment: Imo you should mention everything that was done, software used, settings and so on (or at least provide originals as supporting material)

Comment: Please give more information on your research topic/field.
Personally (Engineering/CS), I do a lot of editing since I want my photos to look great. However, I NEVER do any modifications that change the meaning of my photos. You should keep in mind that your camera already does a lot of stuff internally without telling you. Therefore, adjusting brightness, contrast, color, seems to be fine. Furthermore, I often add labels or remove unrelated stuff that could confuse the reader (e.g., some unused cable in the background that I forgot to remove...)

Comment: @DSVA Depends on the context/field. For astrophotography, sure, but if you are illustrating equipment, for instance, that's unnecessary. I'd say editing is cool as long as you don't compromise/change the point you are trying to make, not its relevance/importance.

Comment: @henning I'm a medievalist (I have a text that describes a church and the picture is of that same church, but it has some modern day external wiring, lamps, and an annoying car that blocks out a ~2mx3m section of the 12mx35m façade) but I figured asking the question in a general case would make the question more useful on here.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm concerned, if you're using someone else's photograph and you don't have a clear set of rules stating that you **can edit it** i would avoid doing so, unless it's a very, very basic thing, like cropping it to hide the cars.

You could also use the legend box commonly written below the picture to help explain it, for example: "Recent picture of a church constructed on the XII century."

If the visual aspect of the church is really important to you could try to recreate how it would look when it was recently constructed (maybe pay a designer to do so) and make it your own thing (of course, referencing the original author: "Recreation of what the church of bla bla bla would look like on the XII century. The original picture was taken by XXXXXX and treated using (...)"